# Cannot export project in Expression Blend for Visual studio 2012

Tags: expression-blend

I have created a WPF prototype in Blend + Sketchflow preview for 2012 and I would like to export screenshots to word however this menu option is not available. I've tried doing it with Blend for Visual studio 2012 as well but it also doesnt expose this option. Any ideas how I can export to word?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using your print screen button? It will capture the screen. If you hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while pressing it, it will only capture the window.